# Using C API of tesseract 3.02 with ctypes and cv2 in python

Tags: python, opencv, ctypes, tesseract

I am trying to use Tesseract 3.02 with ctypes and cv2 in python. Tesseract provides a DLL exposed set of C style APIs, one of them is as following:

```
TESS_API void  TESS_CALL TessBaseAPISetImage(TessBaseAPI* handle, const unsigned char* imagedata, int width, int height, int bytes_per_pixel, int bytes_per_line);
```

So far, my code is as follows:

```
tesseract = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libtesseract302.dll')
api = tesseract.TessBaseAPICreate()
tesseract.TessBaseAPIInit3(api, '', 'eng')
imcv = cv2.imread('test.bmp')
w, h, d = imcv.shape
ret = tesseract.TessBaseAPISetImage(api, ctypes.c_char_p(str(imcv.data)), w, h, d, w * d)
#ret = 44 here
```

The last line return an error code 44, which I can't find anywhere in errcode.h provided by Tesseract. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

I have found similar question [How to recognize data not filename using ctypes and tesseract 3.0.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150937/how-to-recognize-data-not-filename-using-ctypes-and-tesseract-3-0-2), however the question is not resolved.
I am also aware of https://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/, I dig into source code of this project but didn't be able to find the information I need.

I can confirm the image in test.bmp is legit and readable by calling `cv2.imshow`.
also the same image can be OCR by Tesseract on command line.

Comment: I can not help you with the C-Api but if nobody answers: use the [executables to get out the text](https://github.com/niccokunzmann/mousemove/blob/master/mousemove/auslesen.py#L32). It is far away from optimal.

Comment: `TessBaseAPISetImage` doesn't return a value. The default `restype` is `c_int`, so 44 is just garbage converted to an integer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The default `restype` is `c_int`, and the default argument conversion from an integer is also `c_int`. You'll find examples on the web that assume a 32-bit platform that has `sizeof(int) == sizeof(void *)`. This was never a good assumption to make. To protect a 64-bit pointer from truncation when converted to and from a Python integer, set the function pointer's `argtypes` and `restype`. It's a good idea to do this anyway, since it allows ctypes to raise an `ArgumentError` when the the wrong types or number of arguments are used.

If you'd rather not define the prototypes for every function, then at least set `TessBaseAPICreate.restype` to an opaque pointer type.

The following ctypes definitions are based on the header [api/capi.h](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/3.02.02/api/capi.h). For convenience I've packaged the API into a `Tesseract` class.

```py
import sys
import cv2
import ctypes
import ctypes.util

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    LIBNAME = 'libtesseract302'
else:
    LIBNAME = 'tesseract'

class TesseractError(Exception):
    pass

class Tesseract(object):
    _lib = None
    _api = None

    class TessBaseAPI(ctypes._Pointer):
        _type_ = type('_TessBaseAPI', (ctypes.Structure,), {})

    @classmethod
    def setup_lib(cls, lib_path=None):
        if cls._lib is not None:
            return
        if lib_path is None:
            lib_path = ctypes.util.find_library(LIBNAME)
            if lib_path is None:
                 raise TesseractError('tesseract library not found')
        cls._lib = lib = ctypes.CDLL(lib_path)

        # source:
        # https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/
        #         blob/3.02.02/api/capi.h

        lib.TessBaseAPICreate.restype = cls.TessBaseAPI

        lib.TessBaseAPIDelete.restype = None # void
        lib.TessBaseAPIDelete.argtypes = (
            cls.TessBaseAPI,) # handle

        lib.TessBaseAPIInit3.argtypes = (
            cls.TessBaseAPI, # handle
            ctypes.c_char_p, # datapath
            ctypes.c_char_p) # language

        lib.TessBaseAPISetImage.restype = None
        lib.TessBaseAPISetImage.argtypes = (
            cls.TessBaseAPI, # handle
            ctypes.c_void_p, # imagedata
            ctypes.c_int,    # width
            ctypes.c_int,    # height
            ctypes.c_int,    # bytes_per_pixel
            ctypes.c_int)    # bytes_per_line

        lib.TessBaseAPIGetUTF8Text.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
        lib.TessBaseAPIGetUTF8Text.argtypes = (
            cls.TessBaseAPI,) # handle

    def __init__(self, language='eng', datapath=None, lib_path=None):
        if self._lib is None:
            self.setup_lib(lib_path)
        self._api = self._lib.TessBaseAPICreate()
        if self._lib.TessBaseAPIInit3(self._api, datapath, language):
            raise TesseractError('initialization failed')

    def __del__(self):
        if not self._lib or not self._api:
            return
        if not getattr(self, 'closed', False):
            self._lib.TessBaseAPIDelete(self._api)
            self.closed = True

    def _check_setup(self):
        if not self._lib:
            raise TesseractError('lib not configured')
        if not self._api:
            raise TesseractError('api not created')

    def set_image(self, imagedata, width, height,
                  bytes_per_pixel, bytes_per_line=None):
        self._check_setup()
        if bytes_per_line is None:
            bytes_per_line = width * bytes_per_pixel
        self._lib.TessBaseAPISetImage(self._api,
                                      imagedata, width, height,
                                      bytes_per_pixel, bytes_per_line)

    def get_utf8_text(self):
        self._check_setup()
        return self._lib.TessBaseAPIGetUTF8Text(self._api)

    def get_text(self):
        self._check_setup()
        result = self._lib.TessBaseAPIGetUTF8Text(self._api)
        if result:
            return result.decode('utf-8')
```

**Example usage:**

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    imcv = cv2.imread('ocrtest.png')
    height, width, depth = imcv.shape

    tess = Tesseract()
    tess.set_image(imcv.ctypes, width, height, depth)
    text = tess.get_text()

    print text.strip()
```

I tested this on Linux with libtesseract.so.3. Note that `cv2.imread` returns a NumPy array. This has a `ctypes` attribute that includes the `_as_parameter_` hook, set as a `c_void_p` pointer to the the array. Note also that the code shown in the question has the width and height transposed. It should have been `h, w, d = imcv.shape`.

**ocrtest.png:**

[image: ocrtest]

**Output:**

```
I am trying to use Tesseract 3.02 with ctypes and cv2 in python. Tesseract
provides a DLL exposed set of C style APIs, one of them is as following:
```

Comment: Great thanks @eryksun! The fact I was testing in interactive shell mislead me (it returned 44 which makes me thinking the function resulted error)

Comment: I stumbled here from google search and have the same question. However, I am confused from this answer. what does the snippet after the line `This following is based on the header api/capi.h.` do? Is that needed in order to pass a cv2 image to the c api? Or the only thing required would be the snippet after `Example (tested on Linux with libtesseract.so.3)`?

Comment: @Anthony, I rewrote the answer to be more object oriented, and I updated the header link to the new project site on github.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks for the solution. Can you please share, how to change output to HOCR ?

Comment: mypy  error: Name "ctypes._Pointer" is not defined