# How to pass OpenCV image to Tesseract in python?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, tesseract

Given Python code invoking Tesseract`s C API and using **ctypes** library, in the *Option #1* image is being loaded by Tesseract and it works fine! The problem is in the *Option #2*, when I try to pass image loaded by OpenCV the Tesseract returns garbage:

```
from ctypes import *
import cv2

class API(Structure):
    _fields_ = []

lang = "eng"
ts = cdll.LoadLibrary("c:/Tesseract-OCR/libtesseract302.dll")
ts.TessBaseAPICreate.restype = POINTER(API)
api = ts.TessBaseAPICreate()
rc = ts.TessBaseAPIInit3(api, 'c:/Tesseract-OCR/', lang)

##### Option #1
out = ts.TessBaseAPIProcessPages(api, 'c:/Tesseract-OCR/doc/eurotext.tif', None, 0)
print 'Option #1 => ' + string_at(out)

##### Option #2
#TESS_API void  TESS_CALL TessBaseAPISetImage(TessBaseAPI* handle, const unsigned char* imagedata, int width, int height,
#                                             int bytes_per_pixel, int bytes_per_line);

im = cv2.imread('c:/Temp/Downloads/test-slim/eurotext.jpg', cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
c_ubyte_p = POINTER(c_ubyte)
##ts.TessBaseAPISetImage.argtypes = [POINTER(API), c_ubyte_p, c_int, c_int, c_int, c_int]
ts.TessBaseAPISetImage(api, im.ctypes.data_as(c_ubyte_p), 800, 1024, 3, 800 * 3)
out = ts.TessBaseAPIGetUTF8Text(api)
print 'Option #2 => ' + string_at(out)
```

and output is as follows:

> Option #1 => The (quick) [brown] {fox} jumps!
>   Over the $43,456.78  #90 dog
>   & duck/goose, as 12.5% of E-mail
>   from aspammer@website.com is spam.
>   Der ,,schnelleâ€� braune Fuchs springt
>   ï¬�ber den faulen Hund. Le renard brun
>   Â«rapideÂ» saute par-dessus le chien
>   paresseux. La volpe marrone rapida
>   salta sopra il cane pigro. El zorro
>   marrÃ©n rÃ©pido salta sobre el perro
>   perezoso. A raposa marrom rzipida
>   salta sobre o cï¬�o preguicoso.
>
> Option #2 => 7?:5:*:>\â€”â€˜- ;2â€”;i3E:?:;i3".i:    iiâ€˜; 3;â€™ f-iÃ©%*:::â€™::;?:=Â«â€™:: 
>   =Â£<:7â€˜iÂ§5.< :â€”'\â€”;:=Ã©:â€™â€”..=.:a,';2â€™:3â€˜*:3_3:l.':â€”â€˜:â€”:Â£â‚¬:-_â€™:Â§3;;%Â§%ai5~Â«:Ã©::3%iaÂ»â‚¬E:

Remarks:

- I tried python-tesseract and tightocr libraries, which are good
  enough, but lacking documentation
- here I use opencv.imread in order to have possibility to apply math
  algorithms on matrix

Any ideas how to pass OpenCV image (which is numpy.ndarray) to Tesseract? Any help would be useful.

Comment: amazingly...it turns out, it was solved, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21745205/using-c-api-of-tesseract-3-02-with-ctypes-and-cv2-in-python?rq=1).. thanks to @eryksun and stackoverflow!

Answer (score 15):

I use this with python 3: (bw_img is a numpy.ndarray)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

...

(thresh, bw_img) = cv2.threshold(bw_img, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
...

img = Image.fromarray(bw_img)
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(txt)
```